I have to write an SQL query to find the 10th highest salary
I have created a table where I have given 10 entries of employee details as below:
I used the below few queries to fetch the 10th highest salary of the employee:
1).
SELECT * from (
    select emp_id, emp_name, designation, salary, 
    dense_rank() 
    over(order by salary desc) as dr 
    from employee) as top_salary
where dr = 7;

The solution above is giving me 3 records but since I have used dense_rank(), therefore I am having to manually use where dr = 7; or even if I use rank() I will have to use where dr = 8;. But since I can not use dr = 10; when there are duplicate columns, what should be the alternate solution?
2)
SELECT TOP (1) Salary FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP (10) Salary FROM Employee ORDER BY Salary DESC
) AS Emp ORDER BY Salary;

Again, in the above query I am using TOP(10) in postgresql, but it is not working and I understand TOP doesn't work in postgresql.
What other solution can be used for this particular question?
QUERY that is working for me:
SELECT distinct salary,designation,emp_id, emp_name FROM (
  SELECT designation,salary,emp_id, emp_name ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) AS row_num
  FROM Employee
) AS ranked_salaries
WHERE row_num = 10;

&
SELECT distinct(salary),designation,emp_id, emp_name
FROM employee
ORDER BY salary desc limit 1 offset 9;


Are you seriously using postgres 9.5?

What is the expected result when you have ties in the middle or ties for the 10th position? How do you break ties?

Your initial idea is good: that's exactly what dense_rank() is for. In cases when there are multiple employee's with the same salary, their whole peer group will only be counted once.
If your problem with selecting dr=10 is that while it does skip over multiple entries for earlier salaries, it gives you the whole peer group of multiple people who have that 10th highest salary: demo at db<>fiddle
select * from (
    select emp_id, emp_name, designation, salary, 
    dense_rank() 
    over(order by salary desc) as dr 
    from employee) as top_salary
where dr = 10;




emp_id
emp_name
designation
salary
dr




2
emp_name_2
designation_2
100
10


3
emp_name_3
designation_3
100
10



...you can add the limit clause you were already using in later examples:
select * from (
    select emp_id, emp_name, designation, salary, dense_rank()over w1 as dr 
    from employee
    window w1 as (order by salary desc) ) as top_salary
where dr = 10
limit 1;




emp_id
emp_name
designation
salary
dr




2
emp_name_2
designation_2
100
10



If you want a specific one out of those multiple employees, e.g. pick the one with highest id, you can add an order by:
select * from (
    select emp_id, emp_name, designation, salary, dense_rank()over w1 as dr 
    from employee
    window w1 as (order by salary desc) ) as top_salary
where dr = 10
order by emp_id desc
limit 1;




emp_id
emp_name
designation
salary
dr




3
emp_name_3
designation_3
100
10



